# Change scale UIImageView after rotation UIImageView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, rotation, scale

With the use of new scale to my picture, I then apply a rotation, then scale image is getting old scale

```
-(void)rotate:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *)rotationRecognizer{
    double rotation;
    rotation=rotationRecognizer.rotation;
    ((UIImageView*)[rotationRecognizer view]).transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rotation);

    self.photoParent = [self.pictures objectAtIndex:0];

    self.photoParent.rotation =[NSNumber numberWithDouble:rotation];

    NSLog(@"rotation%@",self.photoParent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18802124/1375695).

Applying a "Make.." transform will wipe out any previously-applied transforms. You need to use the cumulative form, `CGAffineTransformRotate`