# Imageview rotation issues in iOS

Tags: ios, image, button, rotation, quartz-2d

I have next task: on button click image have to rotate to 90 degrees.

My code is:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *vector;
@end
```

=========

```
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize vector;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
- (IBAction)rotateOn:(id)sender {
    [self rotateImage:self.vector duration:2
                curve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn degrees:M_PI/2];
}

- (void)rotateImage:(UIImageView *)image duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
              curve:(int)curve degrees:(CGFloat)degrees
{
    // Setup the animation
    [UIView beginAnimations:NULL context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:duration];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:curve];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [image.layer setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0.5,0.5)];
    CGAffineTransform transform =
    CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degrees);
    image.transform = transform;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Before click on the button I have this
[image: Before Click]

After click this
[image: After Click]

You can see that image rotate to 90 degrees. But it moved down from start center point.
Also if I click button again nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using iOS6 and storyboards, try to **disable auto layout** in your storyboard and test the animation again.
If it works, and want to keep auto layout feature, you will need to **adjust your constraints** !

By the way, the default `anchorPoint` is already `(0.5, 0.5)`, the line is not necessary (unless you modify the `anchorPoint` elsewhere):

```
[image.layer setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0.5,0.5)];
```

Comment: I'm idiot :) How i could forget about constraints!?!
Disable auto layout  is solution the issue with changing start position

Comment: disabling autolayout isn't a solution to the problem, it's a hack. I'm having the same problem and I can't figure out how to "adjust my constraints". I have the image view centered in the superview and it is pinned to the bottom layout guide, and it has a fixed width and height.  What constraints are causing this center shift when I rotate?  I hacked it by setting translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to true on the image view.  That doesn't solve the real problem.

Answer (score 1):

inside ur rotation button method use this code to rotate the image by 90

```
static int numRot = 0;
myimage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2 * numRot);
++numRot;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line:

```
  [image.layer setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0.5,0.5)];
```

It doesn't actually do anything as {0.5,0.5} is the default and the centrepoint. You must have been using different values such as {0,0} to get offcentre rotations.

To increment the rotation every time you click the button, you need to use cumulative transforms. The "Make..." transforms are context-free - they do not take previous transforms into account. Instead try this:

```
CGAffineTransform transform; 
transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(image.transform, degrees);
image.transform = transform;
```

You are then adding `degrees` rotation to the current image's transform, rather than resetting the transform to your new value.

Comment: Thanks. You are right!
CGAffineTransformRotate(Transform, Degrees) really rotates image more then one time.

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0);//Upright
imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);//90 degrees clockwise
imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI/2);//90 degrees counter-clockwise
```

also, check your frames

- before you click the button
- after clicking the button, before rotation
- after rotation

You might find anomalies there.